# Installing Bayesgan package in r

Tags: bayesian, generative-adversarial-network

what version of r (rstudio) support the package bayesgan?
I am having this message while trying to install the package :
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘bayesgan’ is not available for this version of R

Try to install bayesgan package

Comment: I don't see any package `bayesgan` on CRAN; there is a `bayesGAM` package - is that what you mean? Please edit the question to add more details about the package, where you are getting it from, and exactly how you try to install it.